# Problems with the "^" sign in ^GSPC in Quantstrat

Tags: r, quantmod, quantstrat

To retrieve stock prices data, I have done the following:

```
options("getSymbols.warning4.0" = FALSE)
tickers <- c("^GSPC","AAPL")
startDate = "1990-01-01"
from = "2006-01-01"
to = "2009-12-31"
getSymbols(tickers, from = from, to = to)
```

However, when I try to apply my strategy unto my portfolio using Quantstrat, an error appeared:

```
> try(applyStrategy(strategy = strategy.st, portfolios = portfolio.st))
Error in get(symbol, envir = envir) : object '^GSPC' not found
```

I have no problems running this with other ticker symbols (eg. NVDA, IBM, ATVI, etc). I believe that the problem lies in the missing "^" in the GSPC in the Global Environment after the getSymbols function is run.

This is the initialisation of my portfolio:

```
initPortf(name = portfolio.st,
          symbols = tickers,
          initDate = startDate,
          currency = "USD")
```

Since the symbols is calling tickers, which contains "^GSPC", and that only "GSPC" is available, I believe this is the reason why the error surfaced, stating that "^GSPC" is not found.

Is there any efficient way to get around this? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to clean your `tickers` from non-alphanumeric characters using the `str_replace_all` function from the `stringr` library before you feed it to quantstrat as the `symbols` argument.

```
library(stringer)
str_replace_all(tickers, "[^[:alnum:]]", “")
```

If you would like to get rid of the carets only:

```
str_replace_all(tickers, "[['^']]", “”)
```

Another option would be using `gsub`to remove unwanted characters.